# Alternativas a Swing de Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Cómo tal vez algunos ya sepan, Oracle ha detenido el desarrollo de la popular librería de interfaz gráfica `Swing`.
Considero a [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) como una tecnología relativamente incipiente como para remplazar `Swing`, por lo cual me gustaría conocer otras librerías de Java (que no sean JavaFX) capaces de remplazar a `Swing`.

Me gustaría consideraran principalmente las siguientes características:

- Facilidad de aprender
- Capacidad de crear interfaces complejas
- Facilidad de integración
- Portabilidad
- Documentación
- Tamaño de comunidad de desarrolladores ( Soporte de la comunidad )
- Soporte pagado ( de la empresa o individuo que lo desarrolla )
- Indicativos de su madurez

**Lo ideal sería migrar el código con swing a la tecnología que comenten.**

Comment: Los que pongan negativos favor de explicar sus motivos ;)

Comment: Pues no lo sabía. A mi también me interesan las respuestas a esta pregunta.

Comment: Es una pregunta muy amplia y depende mucho de la opinión de las personas. Es como preguntar si tengo una aplicación web escrita con Struts 1 y quiero migrarla a un nuevo framework, ¿cuál debería utilizar? La respuesta es amplia y no hay una respuesta definitiva.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza la diferencia es que en este caso se tienen criterios muy específicos, no se trata de preguntar cual es la mejor alternativa, sino que alternativas cumplen con los requerimientos mínimos, lo cual lo hace una pregunta objetiva.

Comment: Es dificil que abarque todos los aspectos que mencionas. Que tal SWT (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)?

Comment: @loki esa es la idea... que sea un contendiente serio... he oído bastante del SWT, principalmente cosas malas... pero si conoces lo suficiente ( o eres capaz de investigarlo :P ) para decir si cumple o no las características, te agradecería conviertas tu comentario a respuesta. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: SWT no solo es un contendiente serio. El famoso IDE Eclipse esta construido utilizando esa tecnología. Ahora bien yo lo he usado y he visto equipos de desarrollo que nunca habían desarrollado en standalone tener éxito con él apoyándose de  un par de libros y de un desarrollador con experiencia.

Comment: @AlvaroC. sería bueno que lo agregaras como respuesta, realmente no sé si siga su desarrollo, aunque solamente he recibido rumores, y me gustaría saber más.

Comment: La última versión estable de SWT es del 27 de junio de 2018, SWT seguirá vivo mientras la gente del proyecto Eclipse sigan considerando que es una buena herramienta. La pregunta esta cerrada por los motivos arriba descritos por lo que no puede agregarse una respuesta. Finalmente: Si lo que se desea es migrar un proyecto que usa Swing a otra cosa, usar SWT sería reescribir toda la vista. Si se trata de iniciar una nueva aplicación debe realizarse una prueba de concepto incluyendo a SWT para ver si aporta a la arquitectura que se este definiendo. Nosotros así lo hicimos y SWT fue el elegido.

Answer (score 5):

Llamas a **JavaFX** "incipiente", nada más lejos de la realidad. Hoy por hoy, la alternativa a Swing que más usa la comunidad, es **JavaFX**. JavaFX es el reemplazo de Swing y te provee nuevas características como:

- FXML
- MVC
- Baja cohesión
- Personalizable vía CSS
- Entre otras

Al ser las vistas de JavaFX hechas en código XML llamado **FXML** y una clase *controladora* que controle los eventos de dicha vista, nos provee de antemano un modelo de programación desacoplado, lo que facilita el desarrollo del patrón **MVC**.

Las vistas son hechas con [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) antes empaquetadas por Oracle, ahora por **Gluon**. Además, soporta un buen número de estilos CSS, pudiendo dejar tus vistas como si de web se tratase. También puedes usar una imagen de photoshop como vistas.

El hecho que la gente esté tan acostumbrada a Swing que no quiera pasar a JavaFX, no quiere decir que sea "incipiente". Bastantes demostraciones se han hecho ya de la potencia de JavaFX.

Comment: La pregunta no es acerca de las capacidades de JavaFX, sino de la facilidad de portar tus aplicaciones a otras librerías gráficas, en ese sentido, JavaFX no sol es incipiente, es pésimo, pues la curva de aprendizaje es alta en comparación a por ejemplo AjaxSwing, en que la conversión es automatizada. Por lo menos el Modelo Vista Controlador y la Baja cohesión ya existían desde hace más de 10 años, no son características nuevas. Nadie quiere interfaces gráficas que trabajes en XML para obtener resultados cercanos a el desarrollo web si lo mismo lo puedes hacer con HTML.

Comment: Tu comentario es incorrecto por varias razones.

- JavaFX no es incipiente, es pésimo. Tiene muchos años ya en el mercado, se han hecho demostraciones muy buenas con JavaFX, tienes webs como FXExperience que te muestran de lo que es capáz JavaFX. Deberías decir: **en mi opinión**, es pésimo.
- JavaFX es compatible con Swing. ¿De qué portabilidad hablas?
- La curva de aprendizaje es 'alta'. Nuevamente, deberías decir **en mi opinión**, por que la curva de aprendizaje es para nada alta.

Comment: - ¿XML es malo para desarrollo de UIs?. Se nota que no has trabajado con JavaFX. No tienes que tocar nada de XML, salvo si quieres. El XML es generado por Scene Builder al crear tus interfaces, es similar al XAML de WPF.

Y como plus, la gracia de poder personalizar tus GUIs como si fuesen web es por **UX** (user experience). Es por esta razón que hay tanta aplicación desktop, móvil o web que no cuentan con un flujo de trabajo intuitivo y tienes que estar adivinando para qué sirve cada opción dentro de la GUI.

Comment: JavaFX surge como competencia para tecnologías ya en decadencia como lo son Flash y Silverlight, no para competir con Swing. La curva de aprendizaje es alta porque si contratas un programador recién egresado es poco probable que ya lo sepa usar, por lo cual te implica gastos operativos, mientras que en AjaxSwing solamente das un par de click y el soporte técnico se encarga de las características que a herramienta no haya podido convertir automáticamente a HTML5.

Comment: El costo de migrar de Swing a JavaFX es complicado, debido a que no todos los componentes de Swing tienen su equivalente, lo que nos lleva a reinventar la rueda mediante el FXML. JavaFX no es un remplazo sino un complemento de Swing, por lo que sería bastante inconsciente migrar interfaces swing a JavaFX. Por ello en la pregunta especifiqué que __no consideraba a JavaFX como una opción de respuesta__, PD: para desarrollo de interfaces con XML hay mejores alternativas como por ejemplo Flex, o el mismo caso de C# para web.

Comment: Toda migración tiene un costo, he migrado una aplicación Swing la empresa a JavaFX y agregué charts, no tuve problema en realidad. Así que el costo no es una cosa de la cual haya que preocuparse en demasía.

Sobre si es reemplazo de Swing o no, lee lo que dice Oracle en la FAQ de JavaFX, punto 6. ¿Aún dices que es inconciente migrar a JavaFX? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html

XML != Web por cierto.

Comment: Ambas, JavaFX y AjaxSwing son opciones totalmente válidas. Hay que ser objetivo y hablar con experiencia; yo no puedo recomendar AjaxSwing porque no lo he probado, pero he probado JavaFX y en base a mi experiencia lo recomiendo.

Saludos.

Comment: Hablando de ser objetivo, (además de que especifiqué que no era una respuesta válida), por lo que me comentan los colegas en su experiencia, respecto a los puntos que especifiqué, no tiene un soporte rápido, le hace falta más documentación, y les ha ocasionado problemas de memoria no librerada y problemas con multiprocesamiento.Cuando vea aplicaciones del tamaño de netbeans, o eclipse portarse a JavaFX lo consideraré como una opción seria, de momento, me ha desagradado la experiencia interactuando con la mayoría de intentos de incluir JavaFX en netbeans exceptuando el navegador embebido.

Comment: Los problemas de memoria y problema de concurrencia son explícitamente del programador. No puedes culpar a una tecnología de ello que ya tiene varios años en el mercado, es ridículo.

Quédate con Swing, pero no puedes decir que algo es pésimo cuando no tienes la suficiente experiencia trabajando con él. Y tendrás que esperar mucho o quizás nunca se llegue a portar Eclipse RPC o NetBeans Platform a JavaFX, no porque "todo será pésimo y costará mucho", si no porque llevaría mucho tiempo.

Hablas de soporte pero, ¿hace cuánto Swing no tiene un major update? Hablemos de experiencias propias.

Answer (score 1):

### AjaxSwing

[image: ajaxswing logo]

He encontrado entre las alternativas una que destaca:

[AjaxSwing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/) de la empresa Creamtec que respecto a los parámetros:

- No se necesita una gran curva de aprendizaje ya que exporta de swing
- Tiene capacidad para interfaces complejas
- Es fácil de integrar
- Tiene una muy alta portabilidad
- cuenta con varios manuales
- Desafortunadamente tiene una comunidad pequeña que afortunadamente se compensa mediante soporte pagado
- En los demos se observa un grado de madurez intermedio

### Dukescript

[image: de swing a dukescript]

Si se desea una opción **gratis**, en algunos meses se dará a conocer una nueva propuesta por parte del personal que desarrolla [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript)

Según el *whitepaper* prometen:

- promete baja curva de aprendizaje, aunque la interfaz se tendría que rehacer parcialmente.
- capacidad sobrada para interfaces complejas mediante [controljs](/questions/tagged/controljs)
- amplia facilidad de integración y pruebas unitarias
- Portabilidad que contempla sistemas de escritorio, web en navegador, [android](/questions/tagged/android) e [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)
- Tendrá [un libro para documentarlo](https://leanpub.com/fromswingtodukescript)
- la comunidad es muy pequeña lo cual presenta una desventaja en la adopción
- Tiene un grado de madurez intermedio, pues de momento la tecnología `Dukescript` tiene soporte para desarrollo únicamente en [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) y [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans).